# How to "grep" a string of a returned result

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How to grep the number `50.0` from the string `temp=50.0'C`

In JavaScript I can use the expression `/temp=(.*?)'C/` to get it.

But I can't get it running in grep.

Comment: `50.0` isn't in the source string, how would you extract it in any language?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Now it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [lookbehinds and lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) after enabling PCRE (via `-P`):

```
root@xxxxxxvlp03 ~ $ echo "temp=50.0'C" | grep -Po "(?<=temp\=).*(?=\'C)"
50.0
root@xxxxxxvlp03 ~ $
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `sed` to extract a matching subgroup in a pretty similar way to your Javascript example:

```
echo "temp=50.0'C" | sed "s/temp=\([^']*\)'C/\1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you know about the string. In this case you could define the wanted result as all the characters which are either a digit or a dot:

```
start cmd:> echo "temp=50.0'C" | grep -Eo '[0-9\.]+'
50.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you can combine conditional addressing and backreferences like this:

```
sed "/temp=\([0-9.]*\)'C/!d;s//=\n\1\n/;s/.*=\n//;P;D"
```

It is admittedly little more than an expansion on godlygeek's answer, but written with an entire file input in mind. It prints only the sequence of digits and .dots occurring between the two strings *temp=* and *'C* - even if multiples occur on the same line - but each *digit|dot* sequence is printed on its own line.

Also note that for maximum portability you should replace the `n`'s in `\n\1\n` with literal newlines if it gives you any trouble - though most `sed`'s will support it as written - like:

```
...//\
\1\
/...
```

Anyway, it enables you to handle the wacky stuff as portably as I know how it can be done. Like:

```
sed "/temp=\([0-9.]*\)'C/!d;s//=\n\1\n/;s/.*=\n//;P;D" <<\DATA
temp=50.0'C
temp=this_is_not_what_you_want'C...temp=92.4'C

some nonsense temp=here
more_nonsensetemp=76.999'Ctemp=56'Ctemp=656'C 
DATA
###OUT###
50.0
92.4
76.999
56
656
```

Its mechanism is fairly simple - it deletes lines not containing your target string. For those that do it selects only the portion you wish to keep and surrounds it on each side with newline characters - and it puts a character known not to be in your target before the first. Then it deletes as much of pattern space as it can while still ending on the arbitrary `=\n` separator.

Last it `P`rints only up to the first newline occurring in pattern space - which we just inserted immediately behind our target - and `D`eletes same before starting a new cycle with what remains.

Answer (score 0):

this may seem helpful if you want just extract the number part of `50.0'C` , you can also use `cut`. it's may seem simple than using regular expression.

`echo "temp=50.0'C" | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d\' -f1`